# Выполняет метод один раз

Tags: c#

Почему метод IsPrime выполняется только один раз? Программа просто входит в вечный цикл.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: код нужно текстом вставлять

Comment: @Alex78191 сейчас поправлю

Comment: При каком n программа зацикливается?

Comment: может вы хотели `isPrime(num)` таки вызывать а не `2` (`prime`)?

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka при любом больше нуля

Comment: @teran так я на простые множители раскладываю число. Если 2 не подошло, то берется следующее простое

Comment: вы лучше сначалал сгенерите массив простых до корня один раз, а потом все тестируйте тогда, а не каждый йраз проверяйте является ли число простым. Тем более +1 делая у вас каждое второе число четным будет

Comment: @kot_mapku3, у тебя ошибка в логике, например, если num == 3, то после num /= prime, оно станет `1`, а при взятии остатка от деления единицы на любое число больше нее будет не нулевой, вот и бесконечный цикл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что prime не меняется, если условие не соблюдается. Возьмем n=1. В if(num%prime) не входим. В else тоже не входим. Не меняется ни n, ни prime. Вот и зацикливание.
Нужно там написать while, чтобы разделить число на данное простое максимальное количество раз, а потом переходить к другому простому.

Comment: А, все, надо вынести в первое условие. Тупанул. Спасибо большое!